# Update progress bar during emscripten webassembly is running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, webassembly, emscripten

I want to show a progress bar during an emscripten webassembly is running. But the progress bar is updatet AFTER the webassembly is finished. Is there a way to either interrupt webassembly (main thread) and then continue or force javascript (main thread) to render the GUI?

main.js

```
Module.cwrap('calc', 'undefined', [])();
```

calc.cpp

```
void calc() {
   EM_ASM({ progressBar($0); }, value); // here the progress bar should be updated immedately
   ...
   calc something
   ...
}
// but it's updated only here
```

I also tried it with

```
progressbar(val) {
   setTimeout(function(){ updateBar(val); }, 0);
}
```

Unfortunately for me it's not possible to use a webworker in a seperate file.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@schteppe: Thxs! For who have the same issue. I solved it with emscripten_async_call().

main.js

```
Module.cwrap('calc', 'undefined', [])();
```

calc.cpp

```
void calc() {
   EM_ASM({ progressBar($0); }, value);
   emscripten_async_call("calcfunction, NULL, msec");
}
void calcfunction() {
   ...
   calc something
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it’s not possible to force the UI to render. I don’t know if it’s possible to interrupt wasm, but here comes an alternative idea.

Consider spreading the calculation out over time instead, and give the main thread (and the event loop) some “breathing room” to update the UI.

Let’s say you’re calculating a sum, and it takes a lot of time in total. You can split your calculation so you can calculate a piece of the sum at a time:

```
var sum = 0;
var i = setInterval(() => {
    sum = calculatePartialSum(sum);
    if(isDone(sum))
        clearInterval(i); // stop
},0);
```

The setInterval with a timeout set to 0 will run the code inside as often as possible, but the main thread (and the UI) can update in between each call.